# Autolayout stretched selected image for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

Creating a button in interface builder with an image for it's selected state but no image for it's default state causes said image to come out distorted when in the selected state. Turning off autolayout fixes this issue.

[image]

Both buttons are the same size. The button ibAction simply toggles selected state. The grey box around the view is simply there so that I'd know where to touch to activate the button since the button has no image for it's default state.

[project zip](https://www.sendspace.com/file/m4fama)

2 questions
1. Why is auto layout f'ing up how button content is displayed? 
2. How do I get this to work in auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

So instead of setting the image property of your `UIButton`, set the backgroundImage property.

I think the reason for this is that auto layout calculates the intrinsic size of your button without taking into account the image property, since it is added on the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to no longer occur in XCode 6 iOS 8. And since my old project is no longer being hosted I can't go back to retest any solutions.